# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, svm, opencv, python

I searched about this issue, I got more questions "the same error" but different code and different reason. So, I was hesitant more to put my issue here. After reading the majority of answers, I didn't find a solution for my issue.

The original and full code [here](https://github.com/mbeyeler/opencv-python-blueprints/tree/master/chapter6)

chapter6.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from datasets import gtsrb
from classifiers import MultiClassSVM



def main():
    strategies = ['one-vs-one', 'one-vs-all']
    features = [None, 'gray', 'rgb', 'hsv', 'surf', 'hog']
    accuracy = np.zeros((2, len(features)))
    precision = np.zeros((2, len(features)))
    recall = np.zeros((2, len(features)))

    for f in xrange(len(features)):
        print "feature", features[f]
        (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = gtsrb.load_data(
            "datasets/gtsrb_training",
            feature=features[f],
            test_split=0.2,
            seed=42)

        # convert to numpy
        X_train = np.squeeze(np.array(X_train)).astype(np.float32)
        y_train = np.array(y_train)
        X_test = np.squeeze(np.array(X_test)).astype(np.float32)
        y_test = np.array(y_test)

        # find all class labels
        labels = np.unique(np.hstack((y_train, y_test)))

        for s in xrange(len(strategies)):
            print " - strategy", strategies[s]
            # set up SVMs
            MCS = MultiClassSVM(len(labels), strategies[s])

            # training phase
            print "    - train"
            MCS.fit(X_train, y_train)

            # test phase
            print "    - test"
            acc, prec, rec = MCS.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
            accuracy[s, f] = acc
            precision[s, f] = np.mean(prec)
            recall[s, f] = np.mean(rec)
            print "       - accuracy: ", acc
            print "       - mean precision: ", np.mean(prec)
            print "       - mean recall: ", np.mean(rec)

    # plot results as stacked bar plot
    f, ax = plt.subplots(2)
    for s in xrange(len(strategies)):
        x = np.arange(len(features))
        ax[s].bar(x - 0.2, accuracy[s, :], width=0.2, color='b',
                  hatch='/', align='center')
        ax[s].bar(x, precision[s, :], width=0.2, color='r', hatch='\\',
                  align='center')
        ax[s].bar(x + 0.2, recall[s, :], width=0.2, color='g', hatch='x',
                  align='center')
        ax[s].axis([-0.5, len(features) + 0.5, 0, 1.5])
        ax[s].legend(('Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall'), loc=2, ncol=3,
                     mode='expand')
        ax[s].set_xticks(np.arange(len(features)))
        ax[s].set_xticklabels(features)
        ax[s].set_title(strategies[s])

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

classifiers.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

__author__ = "Michael Beyeler"
__license__ = "GNU GPL 3.0 or later"


class Classifier:
    """
        Abstract base class for all classifiers

        A classifier needs to implement at least two methods:
        - fit:       A method to train the classifier by fitting the model to
                     the data.
        - evaluate:  A method to test the classifier by predicting labels of
                     some test data based on the trained model.

        A classifier also needs to specify a classification strategy via 
        setting self.mode to either "one-vs-all" or "one-vs-one".
        The one-vs-all strategy involves training a single classifier per
        class, with the samples of that class as positive samples and all
        other samples as negatives.
        The one-vs-one strategy involves training a single classifier per
        class pair, with the samples of the first class as positive samples
        and the samples of the second class as negative samples.

        This class also provides method to calculate accuracy, precision,
        recall, and the confusion matrix.
    """
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def fit(self, X_train, y_train):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def evaluate(self, X_test, y_test, visualize=False):
        pass

    def _accuracy(self, y_test, Y_vote):
        """Calculates accuracy

            This method calculates the accuracy based on a vector of
            ground-truth labels (y_test) and a 2D voting matrix (Y_vote) of
            size (len(y_test), num_classes).

            :param y_test: vector of ground-truth labels
            :param Y_vote: 2D voting matrix (rows=samples, cols=class votes)
            :returns: accuracy e[0,1]
        """
        # predicted classes
        y_hat = np.argmax(Y_vote, axis=1)

        # all cases where predicted class was correct
        mask = y_hat == y_test
        return np.float32(np.count_nonzero(mask)) / len(y_test)

    def _precision(self, y_test, Y_vote):
        """Calculates precision

            This method calculates precision extended to multi-class
            classification by help of a confusion matrix.

            :param y_test: vector of ground-truth labels
            :param Y_vote: 2D voting matrix (rows=samples, cols=class votes)
            :returns: precision e[0,1]
        """
        # predicted classes
        y_hat = np.argmax(Y_vote, axis=1)

        if self.mode == "one-vs-one":
            # need confusion matrix
            conf = self._confusion(y_test, Y_vote)

            # consider each class separately
            prec = np.zeros(self.num_classes)
            for c in xrange(self.num_classes):
                # true positives: label is c, classifier predicted c
                tp = conf[c, c]

                # false positives: label is c, classifier predicted not c
                fp = np.sum(conf[:, c]) - conf[c, c]

                if tp + fp != 0:
                    prec[c] = tp * 1. / (tp + fp)
        elif self.mode == "one-vs-all":
            # consider each class separately
            prec = np.zeros(self.num_classes)
            for c in xrange(self.num_classes):
                # true positives: label is c, classifier predicted c
                tp = np.count_nonzero((y_test == c) * (y_hat == c))

                # false positives: label is c, classifier predicted not c
                fp = np.count_nonzero((y_test == c) * (y_hat != c))

                if tp + fp != 0:
                    prec[c] = tp * 1. / (tp + fp)
        return prec

    def _recall(self, y_test, Y_vote):
        """Calculates recall
            This method calculates recall extended to multi-class
            classification by help of a confusion matrix.

            :param y_test: vector of ground-truth labels
            :param Y_vote: 2D voting matrix (rows=samples, cols=class votes)
            :returns: recall e[0,1]
        """
        # predicted classes
        y_hat = np.argmax(Y_vote, axis=1)

        if self.mode == "one-vs-one":
            # need confusion matrix
            conf = self._confusion(y_test, Y_vote)

            # consider each class separately
            recall = np.zeros(self.num_classes)
            for c in xrange(self.num_classes):
                # true positives: label is c, classifier predicted c
                tp = conf[c, c]

                # false negatives: label is not c, classifier predicted c
                fn = np.sum(conf[c, :]) - conf[c, c]
                if tp + fn != 0:
                    recall[c] = tp * 1. / (tp + fn)
        elif self.mode == "one-vs-all":
            # consider each class separately
            recall = np.zeros(self.num_classes)
            for c in xrange(self.num_classes):
                # true positives: label is c, classifier predicted c
                tp = np.count_nonzero((y_test == c) * (y_hat == c))

                # false negatives: label is not c, classifier predicted c
                fn = np.count_nonzero((y_test != c) * (y_hat == c))

                if tp + fn != 0:
                    recall[c] = tp * 1. / (tp + fn)
        return recall

    def _confusion(self, y_test, Y_vote):
        """Calculates confusion matrix

            This method calculates the confusion matrix based on a vector of
            ground-truth labels (y-test) and a 2D voting matrix (Y_vote) of
            size (len(y_test), num_classes).
            Matrix element conf[r,c] will contain the number of samples that
            were predicted to have label r but have ground-truth label c.

            :param y_test: vector of ground-truth labels
            :param Y_vote: 2D voting matrix (rows=samples, cols=class votes)
            :returns: confusion matrix
        """
        y_hat = np.argmax(Y_vote, axis=1)
        conf = np.zeros((self.num_classes, self.num_classes)).astype(np.int32)
        for c_true in xrange(self.num_classes):
            # looking at all samples of a given class, c_true
            # how many were classified as c_true? how many as others?
            for c_pred in xrange(self.num_classes):
                y_this = np.where((y_test == c_true) * (y_hat == c_pred))
                conf[c_pred, c_true] = np.count_nonzero(y_this)
        return conf


class MultiClassSVM(Classifier):
    """
        Multi-class classification using Support Vector Machines (SVMs)

        This class implements an SVM for multi-class classification. Whereas
        some classifiers naturally permit the use of more than two classes
        (such as neural networks), SVMs are binary in nature.

        However, we can turn SVMs into multinomial classifiers using at least
        two different strategies:
        * one-vs-all: A single classifier is trained per class, with the
                      samples of that class as positives (label 1) and all
                      others as negatives (label 0).
        * one-vs-one: For k classes, k*(k-1)/2 classifiers are trained for each
                      pair of classes, with the samples of the one class as
                      positives (label 1) and samples of the other class as
                      negatives (label 0).

        Each classifier then votes for a particular class label, and the final
        decision (classification) is based on a majority vote.
    """

    def __init__(self, num_classes, mode="one-vs-all", params=None):
        """
            The constructor makes sure the correct number of classifiers is
            initialized, depending on the mode ("one-vs-all" or "one-vs-one").

            :param num_classes: The number of classes in the data.
            :param mode:        Which classification mode to use.
                                "one-vs-all": single classifier per class
                                "one-vs-one":  single classifier per class pair
                                Default: "one-vs-all"
            :param params:      SVM training parameters.
                                For now, default values are used for all SVMs.
                                Hyperparameter exploration can be achieved by
                                embedding the MultiClassSVM process flow in a
                                for-loop that classifies the data with
                                different parameter values, then pick the
                                values that yield the best accuracy.
                                Default: None
        """
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.mode = mode
        self.params = params or dict()

        # initialize correct number of classifiers
        self.classifiers = []
        if mode == "one-vs-one":
            # k classes: need k*(k-1)/2 classifiers
            for _ in xrange(num_classes*(num_classes - 1) / 2):
                self.classifiers.append(cv2.ml.SVM_create())
        elif mode == "one-vs-all":
            # k classes: need k classifiers
            for _ in xrange(num_classes):
                self.classifiers.append(cv2.ml.SVM_create())
        else:
            print "Unknown mode ", mode

    def fit(self, X_train, y_train, params=None):
        """Fits the model to training data

            This method trains the classifier on data (X_train) using either
            the "one-vs-one" or "one-vs-all" strategy.

            :param X_train: input data (rows=samples, cols=features)
            :param y_train: vector of class labels
            :param params:  dict to specify training options for cv2.SVM.train
                            leave blank to use the parameters passed to the
                            constructor
        """
        if params is None:
            params = self.params

        if self.mode == "one-vs-one":
            svm_id = 0
            for c1 in xrange(self.num_classes):
                for c2 in xrange(c1 + 1, self.num_classes):
                    # indices where class labels are either `c1` or `c2`
                    data_id = np.where((y_train == c1) + (y_train == c2))[0]

                    # set class label to 1 where class is `c1`, else 0
                    y_train_bin = np.where(y_train[data_id] == c1, 1, 
                                           0).flatten()

                    self.classifiers[svm_id].train(X_train[data_id, :],
                                                   y_train_bin,
                                                   params=self.params)
                    svm_id += 1
        elif self.mode == "one-vs-all":
            for c in xrange(self.num_classes):
                # train c-th SVM on class c vs. all other classes
                # set class label to 1 where class==c, else 0
                y_train_bin = np.where(y_train == c, 1, 0).flatten()

                # train SVM
                self.classifiers[c].train(X_train, y_train_bin,
                                          params=self.params)

    def evaluate(self, X_test, y_test, visualize=False):
        """Evaluates the model on test data

            This method evaluates the classifier's performance on test data
            (X_test) using either the "one-vs-one" or "one-vs-all" strategy.

            :param X_test:    input data (rows=samples, cols=features)
            :param y_test:    vector of class labels
            :param visualize: flag whether to plot the results (True) or not
                              (False)
            :returns: accuracy, precision, recall
        """
        # prepare Y_vote: for each sample, count how many times we voted
        # for each class
        Y_vote = np.zeros((len(y_test), self.num_classes))

        if self.mode == "one-vs-one":
            svm_id = 0
            for c1 in xrange(self.num_classes):
                for c2 in xrange(c1 + 1, self.num_classes):
                    data_id = np.where((y_test == c1) + (y_test == c2))[0]
                    X_test_id = X_test[data_id, :]
                    y_test_id = y_test[data_id]

                    # set class label to 1 where class==c1, else 0
                    # y_test_bin = np.where(y_test_id==c1,1,0).reshape(-1,1)

                    # predict labels
                    y_hat = self.classifiers[svm_id].predict_all(X_test_id)

                    for i in xrange(len(y_hat)):
                        if y_hat[i] == 1:
                            Y_vote[data_id[i], c1] += 1
                        elif y_hat[i] == 0:
                            Y_vote[data_id[i], c2] += 1
                        else:
                            print "y_hat[", i, "] = ", y_hat[i]

                    # we vote for c1 where y_hat is 1, and for c2 where y_hat
                    # is 0 np.where serves as the inner index into the data_id
                    # array, which in turn serves as index into the results
                    # array
                    # Y_vote[data_id[np.where(y_hat == 1)[0]], c1] += 1
                    # Y_vote[data_id[np.where(y_hat == 0)[0]], c2] += 1
                    svm_id += 1
        elif self.mode == "one-vs-all":
            for c in xrange(self.num_classes):
                # set class label to 1 where class==c, else 0
                # predict class labels
                # y_test_bin = np.where(y_test==c,1,0).reshape(-1,1)

                # predict labels
                y_hat = self.classifiers[c].predict_all(X_test)

                # we vote for c where y_hat is 1
                if np.any(y_hat):
                    Y_vote[np.where(y_hat == 1)[0], c] += 1

            # with this voting scheme it's possible to end up with samples
            # that have no label at all...in this case, pick a class at
            # random...
            no_label = np.where(np.sum(Y_vote, axis=1) == 0)[0]
            Y_vote[no_label, np.random.randint(self.num_classes,
                                               size=len(no_label))] = 1

        accuracy = self._accuracy(y_test, Y_vote)
        precision = self._precision(y_test, Y_vote)
        recall = self._recall(y_test, Y_vote)
        return accuracy, precision, recall
```

when running chapter6.py

The output is:

```
feature None
 - strategy one-vs-one
    - train
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redhwan/Downloads/opencv-python-blueprints-master/chapter6/chapter6.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/redhwan/Downloads/opencv-python-blueprints-master/chapter6/chapter6.py", line 44, in main
    MCS.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/redhwan/Downloads/opencv-python-blueprints-master/chapter6/classifiers.py", line 258, in fit
    params=self.params)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

please help me or your suggestion

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first thing we need to do is identify which parameter is causing the problem.  That means finding a parameter that should be a scalar, a single number, but instead is an array with more than one value.  Here it won't be in `fit` itself, but more likely the `MultiClassSVM` call that creates `MCS`.

Comment: I know the reason but how to fix it? Could you help me, please?

Comment: We don't know the reason.  You haven't identified the relevant variable.